# SQL 2008 Full Text Search Catalog on multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am attempting to setup a full text search catalog in SQL Server 2008 is there a way to make this catalog contain data from multiple tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSMS, you can select as many tables as fields as you like. They just have to be all in the same database.

Comment: Thanks I should have tried it, first but I wasn't too sure.. this works great.